# PHP - Access to variables in class

Tags: php

At this moment, I have somethink like this:

```
/**
 * Fields, which are selected from database for collections of acreditations
 * 
 * @var array
 * @access private
 */
private $selectFields = [ 'firstname', 'lastname', 'additional_info' ];

/**
 * @return array
 */
private function get_selectFields() {
    return $this->selectFields;
}
```

Next in method's I do ex. this:

```
public function myFunction() {
    var_dump( $this->get_selectFields() );
}
```

It's good practice or I should change somethink?

Comment: What's exactly your question or problem?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois About good practice to declare variables in class.

Comment: Function over a function is redundant.

Comment: @u_mulder So, declaring functions with a variable and then refer to this function is useless, right? What in moment, if I need to 'format' content of variable, ex. impode of array?

Comment: If you're interested in PHP coding standards, you could read the PSR: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code with having **private field** and **private method** that simply returns that field doesn't make sense at all. In general `private` modifier is used to limit access to internal properties of one class from another class. In your case you allow to get access to `$selectFields` only for object initiated from this class internally. There is no public interface to get `$selectFields`. Therefore $this->get_selectFields() and $this->selectFields are logically equal because they both return data stored in `$selectFields`.

**Conclusion**: `get_selectFields` is **redundant** and should **be removed** until it will become **public** or start to process/modify `$selectFields` before return.

Answer (score 0):

If your just asking about good practice, which I think you are:
It completely depends how it scales, and gets developed apon. But, what you have presented doesn't have any proper inefficiencies, **assuming** you require those methods to work separately.